# Invoke parameter constructor from Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view that I have listed below.

When I post the form, the default constructor of Organization is getting invoked.
However, I want another constructor to be invoked which takes a Party object.

How to do that in Razor or in any other using mvc, pls advise.

My code:

```
public O(Pobj)
        : this()
    {
        P= obj;
    }
```

View:

```
@using P.M.O


@model IEnumerable<O>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<table>
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.Raw("Caption")
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "O", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <td class="txt">
                    @Html.TextBox("C", item.GetValForProp<string>("C"), new { @class = "txt" }) 
                </td>
                <td class="txt">
                    @Html.TextBox("N", item.GetValForProp<string>("N"), new { @class = "txt" })
                </td>
                <td class="txt">
                    @Html.TextBox("D", item.GetValForProp<string>("D"), new { @class = "txt" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
                </td>
            }
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</td>
```

Added to the above question that is still not resolved, I have got another question.

My Organization is a child of another object Party.
so it will have a property party with party table details that corresponds to organization (orgobj.Party has party object).

When I click on edit, in my controller the orgobj.Party is null and the edits are not working. 
Exception: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Please advise if I am doing something or how can I model bind party of oganization that can be available in edit controller???

Comment: Interesting question but I'm pretty sure you cannot do that. Why don't you just set Party property after the construction?

Comment: You're gonna need to register a custom `ModelBinder` for `Organization` to do so. yet, i'm still curious what will you pass to the constructor that expects `Party`?

Comment: I can pass Party object to constructor that exists within Organization object (orgObj.Party).How to use ModelBinder, can u advise?

Comment: This is kind of bit urgent,can somebody help me or advise if there is any diff way handling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky but can be done under some circumstances. Based upon your code I assume there will be a Party object available when you initiate the Organization object.

The only way I can think of solving this is through a custom ModelBinder. In my example below I'm assuming you have an incoming PartyId parameter that we can use to load a Party object and then initiate the Organization object. You might retrieve the Party object in a different way but that doesn't matter. I'm just showing one way of doing it using the ModelBinder.

```
public class OrganizationModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        // Try to get incoming PartyId
        int partyId = 0;
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("PartyId");
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Missing party id");
        }
        int.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, out partyId);

        // Load Party object from PartyId
        DbContext db = new DbContext();
        Party party = db.Parties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PartyId == partyId);

        if (party == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid party");
        }


        return new Organization(party);

        // If you want to create an instance dynamically based upon the modelType 
        // passed in as an parameter then you'll have to use the following return
        // line instead. 
        // return Activator.CreateInstance(modelType, party);
        //
        // If using this second return line you just have to add one 
        // ModelBinders.Binders.Add(...) line for each and every one of the models
        // you want to use.
    }
}
```

You also have to register your model binder in `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax.cs`

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Organization), new OrganizationModelBinder());
```

This could be working for you...but it all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ohlin, thanks for the reply.Can u advise what is the best place to put this binder? like in which project (my d2admin have all view, my partyweb has got controllers and partybiz has got models)..

Comment: Very good question. It has to be related to the part that binds the model to the database, and in your case that would be partybiz. I might be wrong, but that's where I would try first.

Comment: Hmm thanks. i have tried the binder and it worked great!!! one last question, Is it possible to have a generic binder to all model? I have more than 20, 30 models and it is not so good to have binder for each model, isn't it?

Comment: Do all of these 20-30 models need a party object as well? If you want it to be generic they have to be the same.

Comment: Not Party all the times..Some models have a different parents.If not generics, is there any other way of handling it for all models?

Comment: The problem is that you have different objects that you send into the constructor. I've updated the code above with something that might be able to help you on the way...by using this new way you can use the same ModelBinder for all objects that have Party in the constructor and you can do the same for other objects. I don't know exactly how many different objects you'll have but it might be less than 20-30 as you had in the beginning. I hope it'll help...